# Carga de funciones anónimas en aplicaciones SPA JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de crear una aplicación `SPA` en `JavaScript` siguiendo el modelo incluido en el siguiente  [link](https://codepen.io/ynonp/project/editor/XVvNYO) el cual contiene una función de `route`. El problema esta en que quiero que en una de las paginas que se carge se incluya el plugin de `bootstrap` `Datetimepicker`, el cual se configura con una función anónima.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
  var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
  date_input.datepicker({
  useCurrent: false,
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  container: container,
  todayHighlight: true,
  autoclose: true,
  startDate: "today",
  language: 'es'
  }).on('closeUp',function(){
    var marca = true;
    if(marca == true){
       alert($(this).val());

    }
  })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script> 



<div class="input-group oculto" id="divDate">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
```

Pero esta función no funciona cuando se carga la pagina . La pregunta es, ¿como puedo ejecutar esta función o cualquier otra que se ejecuta como una función anónima? Es algo que después de mucho intentar aun no he conseguido hacerlo funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien la pregunta, lo que ocupabas era llamar la función desde cualquier parte, entonces lo que se puede hacer es crear dicha función, y no solo ejecutarla cuando se carga la pagina(document.ready) cree la función llamar() y dicha funcion la puedes llamar desde donde la ocupes. Yo por ejemplo la llamo cuando hago click en el boton.

```js
function llamar() {
  var date_input = $('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
  var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
  date_input.datepicker({
    useCurrent: false,
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    container: container,
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: "today",
    language: 'es'
  }).on('closeUp', function() {
    var marca = true;
    if (marca == true) {
      alert($(this).val());

    }
  })
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script>



<div class="input-group oculto" id="divDate">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
        <button onclick="llamar()" type="button" id="reporte" class="btn btn-primary" >Click para activar datetimepicker</button>
</div>
```